# Non-square orthogonal matrix $B$ with $B^TB=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

Let $B\in\mathbb{R^{p\times q}},p\geq q$ such that $B^TB=I_q$, is it true that all the diagonal elements of $BB^T$ are all no greater than 1? How can I prove that?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

$P=BB^T$ is an orthogonal projector, $P=P^T$, $P=P^2$. The diagonal elements satisfy
$$
p_{nn}=e_n^TPe_n=e_n^TP^2e_n=\sum_{m=1}^kp_{mn}^2.
$$
So you get
$$
p_{nn}(1-p_{nn})=\sum_{m\ne n}^kp_{mn}
$$
so the left side has to be non-negative.